# How to debug boot when normal mode freezes but recovery mode boots OK

Tags: boot, data-recovery

My Ubuntu (18) sometime freezes at boot with some kernel stack overflow, but sometimes boots and stays OK for a week. Sooner or later it eventually freezes and I have to power it down.

When I boot in recovery mode, then run Networking, su  and startx, computer boots well. (I just cannot set 1920 mode by xrandr but it is different topic)

The question I am asking is not to how to modify boot with nomodeset, but if it is possible to see what extra settings or modules are loaded in normal mode compared to recovery mode, so I can debug it. Thanks